# How to make html select as main options

Tags: php, html-select

How to make options in select HTML as a main viewer.

My mean is, if this code

```
<select>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>four</option>
    <option>five</option>
</select>
```

Run, it will show one when user didn't click that select button yet, but how can I make four as a main without changing the place of that arrangement..

I hope you all understand what I mean..

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
<select>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option selected="selected">four</option>
    <option>five</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
if you want to show four as selected

```
<select>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option selected="selected">four</option>
    <option>five</option>
</select>
```

or

```
<select>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option selected>four</option>
    <option>five</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use selected attribute which you want to select and others leave as it is.

```
<option selected="selected">four</option>
```